# Why are these snippets handled differently by GCC?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, language-lawyer, c++14

The first snippet compiles without any warnings ([live example](https://goo.gl/Jgo7TO)):

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
  constexpr A(): i(5){}
  constexpr operator int() { return 5; }
  int i;
};

int main() {
    A a;
    int b[a]{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    std::cout << b[4] << '\n';
}
```

Now alter the above snippet by returning `i` in the conversion operator ([live example](https://goo.gl/JB6MsK)):

```
constexpr operator int() { return i; }
```

GCC warns that `b` is a VLA.

To me, both variants seem to conform to paragraph §5.19 [expr.const]/3 in C++14.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're performing an l-t-r conversion on `i`, but for [expr.const]/(2.7) not to be violated here, (2.7.3) must be applicable:

[image]

<sup>(2.7.1) concerns complete objects, (2.7.2) talks about string literals and (2.7.4) is about objects whose lifetime began within the evaluation of the expression - inapplicable since `a`'s declaration precedes `b`'s.</sup>

Define `a` as `constexpr` and the code is compliant.

---

A little addendum to clarify what the standard says: The expression inside the brackets must be a converted constant expression of type `std::size_t` ([[dcl.array]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.array#1)), which is defined in [[expr.const]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#4) as

> A *converted constant expression of type* `T` is an expression, implicitly converted to type `T`, where the converted
>   expression is a constant expression and […requirements that are met…]

Thus, really, the standard is interested in whether or not

```
constexpr std::size_t s = a;
```

would be valid. Which it isn't, for the aforementioned reasons - trying to use a subobject of a previously defined, non-`constexpr` object.

Comment: Why does `a` have to undergo an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion in this case? I'm asking this, because the definition of a `converted constant expression` in §5.19/3 (N4140) doesn't seem to require such a conversion from `a` in the declaration `int b[a]{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };`.

Comment: @Ayrosa Well, `a` never has to undergo one, but it's conversion operator must be called in order to convert it to `std::size_t`. (`a` is a converted constant expression of type `std::size_t` inside the brackets)

Comment: It took me a while to really grasp what you said and highlighted in your answer. Definitely, it's not an easy task for one, to fully understand the Standard. Great answer (+1).

Comment: @Ayrosa _id-expression_ `a` has the class type A, but because of the bound of an array must be specified by a converted constant expression of type `std::size_t`, the implementation tries to find implicit conversion sequence to convert it to the destination type. See **[conv] 4\3, 6**. It finds user-defined conversion function `constexpr operator int ()`, which is then used to initialize the temporary of type `std::size_t`, which value would be used as the bound of the array. But!

Comment: @Ayrosa But! The resulting full-expression is not a core constant expression because, though, during that initialization, implied object argument `a` (see **[over.match.conv] 13.3.1.5\2**) is used as an lvalue (there is no l-t-r conversion for it), the conversion function, you defined, evaluate l-t-r for a subobject of `a`, which is not acceptable for a core constant expression, because neither the life-time of `a` begins within the evaluation of the considered full-expression, nor etc...

Comment: @Ayrosa Try to write something like this: `int b[A{}] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};`

Answer (score 4):

Arrays size must be compile-time constants, but in the second example the initialization of `A::i` doesn't happen until *run-time*.

Comment: @YSC Yes, but the variable `a` in the `main` function is not.

Comment: And *this* is the real warning source, isn't it?